# Default global sql_mode setting for server

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

I have the sql_mode on a shared server set to

> ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,​STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,​NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,​NO_ZERO_DATE,​ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,​NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,​NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

What would happen if I removed these variables, and it remains blank? Would it affect other users? Some users want the sql_mode blank, while my thinking is that they should set their own modes using their code.

```
session_start();

include_once("./includes/conn.php");
mysql_query("SET SESSION sql_mode = ''");
```

The whole point of asking this question is to solve the problem at the level its occurring rather than altering a global setting

Comment: MySQL installation programs may configure the SQL mode during the installation process. If the SQL mode differs from the default or from what you expect, check for a setting in an option file that the server reads at startup.

Comment: To change the SQL mode at runtime, set the global or session sql_mode system variable using a SET statement:      SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';